# Setting up jenkins to use an unfuddle git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, unfuddle

We use unfuddle to host our git repositories. 
When we clone a repository, we use:

```
git@oursubdomain.unfuddle.com:oursubdomain/repositoryname.git
```

Jenkins is expecting a url however and says:

```
Specify the URL of this remote repository. This uses the same syntax as your git clone command.
```

In the advanced information for this it says:

```
Specify the repository to track. This can be a URL or a local file path. Note that for super-projects (repositories with submodules), only a local file path or a complete URL is valid. For instance, user@host:/path is not a valid URL
```

So, what I need to know is what URL I should specify to enable this to work. Or even, should I be able to get this to work? I have tried a few things but wondered if anyone had already solved this.

Additional information:

- I'm using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin as
  the git plugin - Jenkins GIT plugin 1.1.23
- I'm using Jenkins on a
  windows machine - Jenkins ver. 1.482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few attempts, I finally worked out that the url

```
git@oursubdomain.unfuddle.com:oursubdomain/repositoryname.git
```

can be used as is, despite what the help suggested.

I have got this to work now, but did need to set up SSH keys etc for the local system account as per the instructions [here](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/jenkins-git-clone-via-ssh-on-windows-7-x64)

Answer (score 0):

git plugin help is indeed wrong, I've fixed this : https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/commit/0b7874d7d8d0ae783697ed55fa25125fecc015d6